# Characteristic classes of quotient manifold

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, group-actions, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a compact oriented smooth manifold with boundary and let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting smoothly, orientation-preservingly and freely on $M$.

(Under what conditions) is there a relationship between the characteristic classes of $M$ and $M/G$?

More specifically, I would like to know if one can determine the Pontrjagin classes of $M/G$ knowing the Pontrjagin classes of $M$. (For a finite group $G$, Don Zagier shows that there is a formula relating them in "The Pontrjagin class of an orbit space", Topology Vol. 11. pp. 253-264. Pergamon Press, (1972). But what if $G$ is infinite, like $G=S^1$ for example?)

Comment: The basic relationship is that for a fiber bundle the tangent bundle of the total space splits as the direct sum of the pullback of the tangent bundle of the base and the vertical tangent bundle. The serre spectral sequence relates the cohomology of the base and the total space, hence how the characteristic classes of the base pull back to characteristic classes of the tangent bundle of the total space.

Comment: Another source of relationships can probably obtained via equivariant cohomology and equivariant char classes

Comment: But these are just comments

Comment: I am skeptical whether there can be a nice relationship: there is a free circle action on $S^{2n+1}$ and the quotient space is $\mathbb CP^{n}$. Letting $n$ vary and taking products we can produce arbitrary Pontryagin numbers for the quotient spaces. But spheres are stably parallelizable...